# Change Link in Django Suit

Tags: django, django-admin, django-suit

I'm using Django Suit for my admin, but I would like the change links to be linked from the model name (like in the standard Django admin) instead of from a separate "change" link. How can I remove the "change" link and make the model title itself the link?

For example, in the attached image, I would like to link to the change pages from the first column, instead of using that separate  "change" link.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If these are different models, then you would modify the config section in settings. That is of course assuming that you want them to appear as menu links on the left side.

You would do that like so :

```
SUIT_CONFIG = {

  'MENU': (

    # Keep original label and models
    'sites',

    # Rename app and set icon
    {'app': 'auth', 'label': 'Authorization', 'icon':'icon-lock'},

    # Reorder app models
    {'app': 'auth', 'models': ('user', 'group')},

    # Custom app, with models
    {'label': 'Settings', 'icon':'icon-cog', 'models': ('auth.user', 'auth.group')}, `
```

Check out [The Docs](https://django-suit.readthedocs.org/en/develop/configuration.html#menu) for more

Comment: Thank you for your help @thebrezilien but I'm trying to change the links on the main part of the admin 'home' page, not in the side menu. The screen shot is of the `/admin` page and I would like to hyperlink the model names (Categories, Cities, Continent, Countries, etc) to their list of all objects instead of using the separate "change" link like it currently does...?

Comment: I think I can get this done by overriding the admin index.html but I wanted to make sure there wasn't already an easier way via Django Suit...?